# Issue with triangles borders in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am facing an issue with drawing triangle borders using Matplotlib in Python. I want  to create a specific pattern, but I'm encountering unexpected behavior. I need assistance in identifying and resolving the problem.

this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 5
A = np.array([(x, y) for y in range(N, -1, -1) for x in range(N + 1)])
t = np.array([[1, 1], [-1, 1]])
A = np.dot(A, t)

# I have defined a triangle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
triangle = fig.add_subplot(111)

X = A[:, 0].reshape(N + 1, N + 1)
Y = A[:, 1].reshape(N + 1, N + 1)

for i in range(1, N + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        line_x = np.array([X[i, j + 1], X[i, j], X[i - 1, j]])
        line_y = np.array([Y[i, j + 1], Y[i, j], Y[i - 1, j]])
        triangle.plot(line_y,line_x,  color='black', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

but I am getting this image, as u can see, [image]

At corner extra lines are coming, as i encircled it. I dont want this extra line, i tried to solved it using loop, eventhough one extra line will keep remain

```
for i in range(6):
    if i == N-1 :
        for j in range(i-1):
            line_x = np.array([X[i , j+1], X[i, j],X[i-1, j]])
            line_y = np.array([Y[i, j+1], Y[i, j], Y[i-1, j]])
            triangle.plot(line_y, line_x, color='black', linewidth=1)
        pass
    else:
        for j in range(i):
            line_x = np.array([X[i , j+1], X[i, j],X[i-1, j]])
            line_y = np.array([Y[i, j+1], Y[i, j], Y[i-1, j]])
            triangle.plot(line_y,line_x, color='black', linewidth=1)
        pass
```

plt.show()
kindly resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you want to delete belong to the triangules generated in the first (i = 1, j = 0) and last (i = N, J = N - 1) iterations of the nested `for` loops:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
A = np.array([(x, y) for y in range(N, -1, -1) for x in range(N + 1)])
t = np.array([[1, 1], [-1, 1]])
A = np.dot(A, t)

# I have defined a triangle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
triangle = fig.add_subplot(111)

X = A[:, 1].reshape(N + 1, N + 1)
Y = A[:, 0].reshape(N + 1, N + 1)

for i in range(1, N + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        if i == 1: # Lower right triangle
            line_x = np.array([X[i, j + 1], X[i, j]])
            line_y = np.array([Y[i, j + 1], Y[i, j]])
        elif j == N - 1: # Upper right triangle
            line_x = np.array([X[i, j], X[i - 1, j]])
            line_y = np.array([Y[i, j], Y[i - 1, j]])
        else:
            line_x = np.array([X[i, j + 1], X[i, j], X[i - 1, j]])
            line_y = np.array([Y[i, j + 1], Y[i, j], Y[i - 1, j]])
        triangle.plot(line_x, line_y,  color='black', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, 
small doubt if i use 
for i in range(1, N):
insted of 
for i in range(1, N+1):
than where should i change, since one cell will dlete, kindly help

Comment: Hi, please help,

Comment: The problem is that the iteration `i = N` of the first for loop generates all the upper triangles (5 for N = 5) and not just the last one. What is simple is to eliminate the first iteration (`for i in range(2, N + 1):`) since it only generates one triangle (which is also the one you want to modify), and you can generate it  outside the cycle.

Comment: I am new so i cant do as u told, if possible, kindly modify the loop, otherwise i have to make seperate loop for code for drawing line , I want to keep it like this for i in range(1, N ), so that in one loop i can perform all task. thank you

Comment: It is not clear to me why you want to remove that iteration, when in your own original code you use the same loop, but keep in mind that if you remove an iteration of the for loop you will have to create another loop later to draw the missing triangles, because at least you will be missing a trinagle to draw.

If you need the variable `i` for other things in the loop, simply discard the last iteration with a conditional (`if i != N: #Do whatever`).

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your clever method draws open triangles, and you say that the last, rightmost columns of open triangles has too much sides...

I have another clever method to draw a "pyramid of squares", as this is what you seem to want.

---

Update

I noticed that I always used `N-1` in my previous code (see the edit history), so I decided to deviate from the OP and use `N` to tell the number of squares to be drawn on the long sides.

[image]

```
def pyramid_of_squares(N, ax=None):
    from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
    from numpy import array
    
    if N<1 : raise ValueError("N must be > 0 (strictly positive).")
    
    def P(x, y): return array((x, y))
    def draw(p0, p1): ax.plot(*zip(p0, p1), 'k', lw=0.75)
    
    p0 = P(0, 0)
    ptop = P(N, N)
    pbot = P(N,-N)
    dp1, dp2 = P(1, -1), P(-1,-1)
    
    if ax is None: fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(4, 7))
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    draw(p0, ptop)
    draw(p0, pbot)    
    for i in range(N):
        j = i+1
        draw(p0+dp1*j, ptop+dp1*j+dp2*i)
        draw(p0-dp2*j, pbot-dp2*j-dp1*i)
    return ax

from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots
fig, axs = subplots(1, 3, figsize=(9, 4))
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    pyramid_of_squares(1+i*3, ax)
```